# Refresh the main page on close of popup window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

I am opening the popup window with the below code from Server side

```
var url = string.Format("../UserPopup.aspx?user_Ids={0}&fromDate={1}&toDate={2}", user_Ids, fromDate, toDate);
string script = string.Format("function f(){{openDialog('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3});Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}}Sys.Application.add_load(f);",
                                     url,
                                     "true",    
                                     1000,
                                     300);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true)
```

Below is the code for closing the popup window from javascript. The below code is not working.

```
function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }

function Close() {
var result = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to close the window!");
if (result == true) {
    var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
    oWindow.argument = null;
    oWindow.onunload = refreshParent;
    oWindow.close();
    return false;
    } 
 }

 function refreshParent() {
     window.opener.location.reload(); 
 }
```

The  `window.opener.location.reload();` does not work at all here. Don't know the reason.

**How can I refresh the parent page on close of popup?**

Comment: So you mean to say that you are not able to close the child window and unable to refresh the parent as well right?

Comment: I am able to close the window if I remove `oWindow.onunload = refreshParent;` from `Close` function. I only need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the OnClientClose event, something like:

**On the main page**

```
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" OnClientClose="OnClientClose"></telerik:RadWindow>
        <script>
            function OnClientClose(sender, args) {
                if (args.get_argument()) { //make the condition more complex, depending on the argument you pass
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

**On the content page**

```
            function Close() {
                var result = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to close the window!");
                if (result == true) {
                    var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
                    oWindow.close(someArugment); //pass the argument here. Define it first, of course
                }
            }
```

This demo has an working example as well http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window

Answer (score -1):

you can use partial view model for that, first add below code to your partial view and 'mymodel' in main view,

```js
<div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Event Information</h4>
        </div>

 <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

now here is your close button javascript file in which just hide 'mymodel' control

```js
 $(function () {
     

        $("#closbtn").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your both codes throw error and I cannot use your code. This is a drastic change from my code. I am using  Telerik RadWindow for this.

Comment: Here I am using RadWindow for this.

Comment: I am opening the popup window from Server Side. Due to this I am unable to use your code.